# I'm trying to add 5 to all elements in array and i have used numpy for that but i'm getting this error could please tell me what i'm doing wrong

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

```
from numpy import *

val = array([22,3,4,66,77,88])
val = val + 5
print(val)


"C:\Users\PycharmProjects\FirstProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users//PycharmProjects/FirstProject/random.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/FirstProject/random.py", line 1, in <module>
    from numpy import *
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\FirstProject\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 151, in <module>
    from . import random
  File "C:\Us\PycharmProjects\FirstProject\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\__init__.py", line 179, in <module>
    from . import _pickle
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\FirstProject\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_pickle.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .mtrand import RandomState
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1, in init numpy.random.mtrand
  File "bit_generator.pyx", line 40, in init numpy.random.bit_generator
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\secrets.py", line 20, in <module>
    from random import SystemRandom
  File "C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\FirstProject\random.py", line 3, in <module>
    val = array([22,3,4,66,77,88])
NameError: name 'array' is not defined
```

Comment: Your question is poorly formatted and really hard to read. Take a look on [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to know ways to improve it.

Comment: Use `val = np.array([22,3,4,66,77,88])`.  And `import numpy as np`.  Note that ` ... import *` is generally bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

Dont import `numpy` with an asterisk.
`import numpy as np` is pretty common.

The problem with asterisk import is that you import all functions from the given package as they are. And in most cases there will be an overlap between the imported function names and python-implicit functions or variables/functions defined by the user.

Comment: By “pretty common”, you mean [documented convention](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)?  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to use [numpy.**array**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) you could import it specifically like so:

```
from numpy import array

val = array([22, 3, 4, 66, 77, 88])
val = val + 5
print(val) # [27  8  9 71 82 93]
```

Most likely you would like to use other things available in numpy so you can refer to it explicitly after importing the whole numpy package:

```
import numpy

val = numpy.array([22, 3, 4, 66, 77, 88])
val = val + 5
print(val) # [27  8  9 71 82 93]
```

Typing `numpy` every time is tedious so you can use the convention to refer to it as `np`:

```
import numpy as np

val = np.array([22, 3, 4, 66, 77, 88])
val = val + 5
print(val) # [27  8  9 71 82 93]
```